# Desktop shortcut icon overriding app icon

Tags: winapi, shortcut-file

We have an application that is installed with a desktop shortcut icon that is different than the application icon. So, the result we are aiming at is:

- a desktop shorcut with icon A, pointing to our application
- once clicked, the application will launch with it's own icon B

However, the observed behaviour is that our application is launched with the shortcut icon A visible in the start menu bar, and the proper app icon B visible in the title bar. Is there an option to override this behaviour?

We are using InnoSetup for our installer, if that matters.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150812-00/?p=91831

Comment: I have never really understood why people do this. Why should your desktop shortcut icon be different than your application's icon? That just makes it hard on users when they're inevitably presented with your application icon but it doesn't match the icon they clicked to start the app. Bad UX all the way around, even if you fix this bug. Make the app's icon the app's icon. Use the *name* of the shortcut to clarify, or the "Comment" field which will show as a tooltip.

Comment: @CodyGray Think launcher / updater. We create a desktop shortcut with the target app icon (so the user is not confused), the launcher opens (and should have it's own icon), updates the target app and launches it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution - having the process restart itself will fix the problem. It's pretty clumsy, but it works. I'll mark this as an accepted answer unless somebody has a better suggestion.